# Can facebook Prophet be applied to sparklyr via spark_apply

Tags: sparklyr, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to test if I can run prophet with sparklyr to make forecast for data in cluster. But when I use spark_apply the program is stuck.

Running sparklyr on an edgenode connected to a yarn-client with spark 2.2.0.
The data is sales by locations spanning last 4 years.

The plan is to create a dataframe with all the data and partition the data by locations then call prophet on each location and get prediction for the next 7 days.

Here I tried to pull data for one location and apply prophet but sparklyr was stuck.

```
library("sparklyr")
library("prophet")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client",version = "2.2.0"))
query = "select * from saletable"
df <- sdf_sql(sc,query) %>%
         filter(locationid=="1111") %>% 
         select(date,sales) %>%
         sdf_repartition(partitions=1) %>%
         select(ds=date,y=sales)

## try to predict sales the next 7 days and get the predictions

sparkly_prophet <- function(df){
    m <- prophet::prophet(df)
    future <- prophet::make_future_dataframe(m,periods=7,freq='day')
    forecast <- predict(m,future)
    return (dplyr::select(forecast,yhat) %>% tail(7))
}

Then I run but it gets stuck

spark_apply(df,sparkly_prophet)
```

Answer (score 1):

When I've used `spark_apply()`, I've had better success including the function definition within the call to `spark_apply()`. I'm not sure why this is, but it may be worth a short to restructure your code as

```
spark_apply(
  df, 
  function(df) {
    m <- prophet::prophet(df)
    future <- prophet::make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 7, freq = "day")
    forecast <- predict(m, future)
    yhat <- dplyr::select(forecast, yhat) 
    return(tail(yhat, 7))
  }
)
```